# What's the right way to search a Rails model by multiple IDs in a more advanced query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, select, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and PostGres 9.5.  How do I write a Rails query that returns results based on finding multiple IDs?  I have this

```
    criteria = "my_objects.id IN ?"
    param = "(#{params[:ids]})"
...
  @results = MyObject.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON my_objects.address_id = addresses.id")
                 .where("#{criteria} AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_object_times WHERE my_object_times.my_object_id = my_objects.id)", param)
                 .order(order_by)
                 .paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

The IDs are passed in via a query string parameter, taht looks something like

```
ids=9e24abc1-1422-4e51-9d0b-72ea444f8110,dcba2558-9bcc-48a2-b5ba-61b230aa796f
```

but the above results in the error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'(9e24abc1-1422-4e51-9d0b-72ea444f8110,dcba2558-9bcc-48a2-b5ba-61b230aa796f)'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an array as a parameterized value to the query:

```
ids = params[:ids].split(',')

@results = MyObject.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON my_objects.address_id = addresses.id")
  .where("my_objects.id IN ? AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_object_times WHERE my_object_times.my_object_id = my_objects.id)", ids)
  .order(order_by)
  .paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Additionally you should be able to replace `AND EXISTS` by doing a INNER LEFT join:

```
@results.left_outer_joins(:addresses)
        .joins(:my_object_times)
        .where(id: ids)
```

`left_outer_joins` is new in Rails 5.

Comment: There is a substantial performance differnce to replacing AND EXISTS with the join you suggest, no?

Comment: Try it out and see.